# Split diagonally div in 3 divs

Tags: html, css

Trying to achieve something as the image suggests, and not sure what would be the best approach because I want to play with the divs heights when hovering.

The container div must be 100% width, 100% height and the divs inside fully responsive.

Borders, pseudos or background wont work for this particular case.

[image]

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="top"></div>
  <div class="center">
    <p>text text</p>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container{
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow: hidden;
     //  transform: skewY(-45deg);
     //  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.top, .bottom {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(50% - 20px);
}
.top {
    background: black;
}
.bottom {
    background: grey;
}
.center {
    background: green;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
}
p {
  color: white;
  line-height: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

In the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ttmh8ant/4/) you will find both rotate and skewY commented.

Comment: try this answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142498/split-div-with-diagonal-line

Comment: Why dont you use a gradient background

Comment: Not sure if I will be able to animate the hold thing with gradient backgrounds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it works for you.

If want pure CSS solution, you can try this.
It uses **Area of Traingle** and all other calculations.
I have given `width: 300px;height:600px;` to `parent DIV` and then done the calculations. You may need to change accordingly.
I use `SCSS` for writing my CSS, so its easy for me. Though I have tried to do more of calculation using `calc` to make it more CSS friendly.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
  /* Not relevant. this was used to show a Guide-point of intersection of one of triangle's side. 
  &:before {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
    top: -1px;
    display: block;
  }
  &:after {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
    bottom: -1px;
    display: block;
  }
  */
}

.child {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.child:hover {
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
}

.child:hover~.child {
  height: 20px;
}

.child__inner {
  transform: skewY(30deg);
  color: #fff;
}

.child--top {
  background: tomato;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin-top: calc((150px / 1.73)* -1);
  padding-top: calc((150px / 1.73) * 2);
}

.child--middle {
  background: DeepSkyBlue;
}

.child--bottom {
  background: MediumSeaGreen;
  height: calc(50% - 20px);
  margin-bottom: calc((150px / 1.73)* -1);
  padding-bottom: calc((150px / 1.73) * 2);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child--top">
    <div class="child__inner">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus, accusantium. Illo minima ipsa, at dignissimos perspiciatis nesciunt. Hic quae porro assumenda possimus fugit, velit eaque magni, reiciendis veritatis perspiciatis recusandae?
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child child--middle">
    <div class="child__inner">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="child child--bottom">
    <div class="child__inner">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to check the **SCSS**, below is the code.

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 600px;
  /* Not relevant. this was used to show a Guide-point of intersection of one of triangle's side. 
  &:before {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
    top: -1px;
    display: block;
  }
  &:after {
    content: '';
    width: 2px;
    height: 2px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: calc(50% - 1px);
    bottom: -1px;
    display: block;
  }
  */
}

.child {
  min-height: 20px;
  padding: 15px;
  transform: skewY(-30deg);
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;

  &:hover {
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
  }
  &:hover ~ .child {
    height: 20px;
  }
  &__inner {
    transform: skewY(30deg);  
    color: #fff;
  }
  &--top {
    background: tomato;
    height: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin-top: calc((150px / 1.73)* -1);
    padding-top: calc((150px / 1.73) * 2);
  }
  &--middle {
    background: DeepSkyBlue;
  }
  &--bottom {
    background: MediumSeaGreen;
    height: calc(50% - 20px);
    margin-bottom: calc((150px / 1.73)* -1);
    padding-bottom: calc((150px / 1.73) * 2);
  }
}
```

**Reference**: [Area of Traingle and Sides height/width](https://www.freemathhelp.com/triangle-30-60-90.html)

Comment: looking good, do you think that is possible to change the proportions when hovering with this method? i.e. when hovering the tomato div height will increase, the DeepSkyBlue will move down and the MediumSeaGreen div height will decrease?

Comment: Other option not pure css would be calculating sizes with js, right?

Comment: Yes, animating on hover is possible. It will again require some calculations as it has to be in proportion.

Comment: @TyraPululi i have updated the answer with basic animations. You can modify or customize to your requirement. It would require some efforts, but it is possible.

Comment: I am having a small issue, I need to have some text inside the top div and the bottom div but I cant really find how to position the text.

Comment: @TyraPululi there is a div called `child__inner` . Add your text inside that div.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .gradient{ width: 250px; height: 500px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0% , #000 45%, #53ff00 45%, #53ff00 50%, #7e7e7e 50%, #7e7e7e 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0% , #000 45%, #53ff00 45%, #53ff00 50%, #7e7e7e 50%, #7e7e7e 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(-45deg, #000 0% , #000 45%, #53ff00 45%, #53ff00 50%, #7e7e7e 50%, #7e7e7e 100%);
  
  }
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

You can also use linear gradient

Comment: thanks for the reply, I was trying to avoid this method because of the hovering.

Answer (score 0):

Its so easy use **border** style:

```css
#id1 {
        background-color: #53ff00;
            position: relative;
            width:100px;
    }
    #id2 {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        border-top: 100px solid #000;
        border-right: 100px solid transparent;      
    }
    #id3 {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
       border-bottom: 100px solid #969696;
        border-left: 100px solid transparent;
       margin-top:-65px
    }
    #top{
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #000;
        width:100px;
    }
    #bottom{
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #969696;
        margin-top: -4px;
        width:100px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="top"></div>
    <div id="id1">
      <div id="id2"></div>
      <div id="id3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="bottom"></div>
```

complete shape of CSS this link : [The Shapes of CSS](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Pseudo elements also wont work in this case. The container must be 100% width and height and fully responsive.