# How to make a multi-colored header

Tags: html, css, colors, header

Very simple question, can you make a header like the one demonstrated in the quick MS paint image below? I don't know if this is possible in HTML/CSS and i'm relatively new to it all: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5IuV.png

Comment: Yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38142498/split-div-with-diagonal-line for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
#main {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, red 50%, white 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <p>some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: better and most simplicit solution then your previos attempt. With that you only need that actual element + a single property

Comment: @tacoshy sorry I'm a backend guy mostly lol so I didn't even consider gradient. Thanks for the tip,